# Why does the following element appear at both the head and tail of this c++ vector after a call to erase and push_back?

Tags: c++, new-operator, stdvector

I'm trying to understand why the following code behaves the way it does:

```
std::vector<int*> k;
for (int i = 0; i < 5; ++i) k.push_back(new int(i));

for (int i = 0; i < k.size(); ++i)
    std::cout << "k[" << i << "]: " << *k[i] << "@" << k[i] << ", ";
std::cout << std::endl;

for (int i = 0; i < k.size(); ++i) {
    int* p = k[i];
    delete p;
    if (i >= 2) {
        k.erase(k.begin(), k.begin() + i);
        k.push_back(new int(5));
        break;
    }
}

for (int i = 0; i < k.size(); ++i)
    std::cout << "k[" << i << "]: " << *k[i] << "@" << k[i] << ", ";
std::cout << std::endl;
```

When I run this, the first time we print the contents of `k` I see this:

```
[0]: 0@0x1774e010, k[1] 1@0x1774e050, k[2]: 2@0x1774e030, k[3]: 3@0x1774e070, k[4]: 4@0x1774e0c0
```

This is what I expected. Then after the erase and the push i would expect the first two elements to be gone, the last three to be shifted, and the 5th one to appear at the end. However, i get this instead:

```
k[0]: 5@0x1774e030, k[1]: 3@0x1774e070, k[2]: 4@0x1774e0c0, k[5]: 5@0x1774e030,
```

I do see `k[5]` appearing at the end after the rest of the elements shifted but I am not understanding why it also appears as the first element too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The second argument to `vector::erase` is a *one past the end* iterator. This is the typical form for iterator ranges in the standard C++ library.

So, when `i == 2` the statement `k.erase(k.begin(), k.begin() + i)` only erases the first two elements, leaving the one you just deleted still in the vector. This goes on to cause bogus results when you try to use the deleted pointer.

(Technically it is undefined behaviour to do the `erase` also, since it involves reading the deleted pointer).

Possibly, the reason you see `k[0]: 5@0x1774e030` instead of random garbage would be that your `new int` reallocates into the same space you just `delete` ; and I guess `k[5]:` on that line is a typo for `k[3]:` .

Comment: That's exactly right! Thanks, I stared at this for a long time and it kept eluding me...